# UITapGestureRecognizer to hide and unhide the label data with swift4

Tags: ios, swift4

I need `UITapGestureRecognizer` to both hide and unhide the value. User with single tap should hide the label value and with the single tap should unhide the label, is there any way I could perform this operation?

Now I have used tap and long-tap gesture to perform this operation. Below is my code,

```
let tab = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(availabelBalance))
tab.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
tab.cancelsTouchesInView = false
accountBalanceView.addGestureRecognizer(tab)

let tabTwo = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(availabelBalanceTwo))
accountBalanceView.addGestureRecognizer(tabTwo)
```

Comment: take use default bool value one user tabs one time save its status when tabs again get that status.

Answer (score 0):

You only need tapGesture

```
let tab = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(availabelBalance(_:)))
tab.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
tab.cancelsTouchesInView = false
accountBalanceView.addGestureRecognizer(tab)
```

//

```
@objc func availabelBalance(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    if lbl.text == "" {

        lbl.text = value
    }
    else {

         lbl.text = ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you hide the label then you will not able to touch again that label as it is hidden now.

To hide a label you can you this trick.

When you tap on label then you can check that...

```
var tempText = "" //temperory property to store value or label

@objc func tapDetected(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    if let text = label.text, !text.isEmpty {
        tempText = lbl.text.text
        label.text = " "
    } else {
        label.text = tempText 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code

```
import UIKit

class firstViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var textLbl: UILabel!
var tab : UITapGestureRecognizer?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tab = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(availabelBalance))
    tab?.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tab?.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tab!)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@objc func availabelBalance(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    if (tab?.cancelsTouchesInView)! {
        textLbl.isHidden = true
        tab?.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    }else{
        textLbl.isHidden = false
        tab?.cancelsTouchesInView = true
    }

}

}
```